# Best practices for debugging OSX entitlement or sandbox problems?

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I have a local development builds of an audio software application, and I'm having problems setting up entitlements so that I can receive audio input (`com.apple.security.device.audio-input` and/or `com.apple.security.device.microphone`). This works correctly for "official" builds produced via an IBS pipeline, but never locally.

**Based on everything I can see**, my local builds are correctly configured - my build is signed and `codesign` shows the correct entitlements. The app requests other permissions for e.g. disk access. The application appears and is checked in "Security and Privacy" under "Microphone". However: my audio input is silent, and I am not asked for permissions when opening an input device (this is not a code issue: for example, the identical commit hash built on another system, and run on my system work fine). For now, I'm only concerned with my local builds being *usable* - these are not official / app store builds, or intended for use on other systems than my dev system.

**This is not a question** about "how to do entitlements", or about this entitlement specifically, but more generally - **how do I debug this issue**:

- Are there other a priori ways to check my entitlements beyond `codesign  --display --entitlements`? Where else should I check that, for a given application / binary, entitlements are set up correctly?
- When the application attempts to open an a audio input, and access is denied (presumably) because of entitlements, is this failure logged (syslog etc)?
- Are there Apple API's that can provide more detailed error information when an operation fails because of entitlements? Can I log the details of an entitlement failure myself?
- I have *many* builds of the application on my system - debug builds, release builds, branches, old versions etc., but only ever see a single application in e.g. Security and Privacy UI. How can I verify that what I see in the UI is correct for e.g. the particular app package / identifier I'm working with?

Any other debugging tips or workflows would be appreciated.

One note: the build system for this project is Cmake/make/command-line-based rather than Xcode based - all entitlements/signing stuff is being done via Cmake and command line tools (again: this has worked before, and works for some builds), so I would prefer solutions that matched this workflow - Apple's documentation is good, but is usually of the form "do this in Xcode", which is unhelpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Display all entitlement-related logs (in Terminal):

```
log show --predicate 'eventMessage CONTAINS "entitlement"'
```